Modifying kafka mongodb connector for deletion operation
I am going to make 3 db of atlas consist of 1 source and 2 sink and make cdc with all changes. However, even though I tried all the properties on the Internet, when I insert and change the document on the source, the sink changes in real time, but when I delete the document on the source, it is not deleted from the sink. When I changed "publish.full.document.only": "true" to false, I was able to confirm that a delete message was delivered to the sink, which was also confirmed in the docker's log.
So in conclusion, I want to use "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector" while copying the document at the same time using "publish.full.document.only": How can I fix this by changing the connector?
{
  "name": "mongo-Diary-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb+srv://id:pw@keaprofit.2ttoq3v.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=KEAProfit",
    "database": "Arcadia",
    "collection": "Diary",
    "topics": "Arcadia.Diary",
    "poll.max.batch.size": "1000",
    "poll.await.time.ms": "5000",
    "name": "mongo-Diary-source-connector",
    "copy.existing": "true",    
    "publish.full.document.only": "true"
    }
}

{
  "name": "mongo-Diary-sink-connector1",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "Arcadia.Diary",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb+srv://id:pw@keaprofit2.yyjyfhn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=KEAProfit2",
    "name": "mongo-Diary-sink-connector1",
    "database": "Arcadia",
    "collection": "Diary"
  }
}

